# iPhone sqlite sync with sqlite on dekstop/mac

Tags: iphone, sqlite, synchronization

Can I sync the local sqlite database on desktop/mac with sqlite database on iPhone for application by directly connecting the phone to my mac/pc?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable iTunes document sharing with `UIFileSharingEnabled` in the info.plist and then copy the sqlite database file to the Documents directory in your application, if it isn't there already.

I've been able to do this and was able to read the file just fine with sqlite on the desktop.

unfortunately it isn't automatic. Someone would need to go into iTunes and manually copy the file over each time.